# Definite integral02

Tags: calculus

Find
$\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{dx}{1-2a \cos{x}+a^2 }$
My turn
Let $$\tan{\frac{x}{2}}=u$$
But i got confused while determining the new limits because
$$\tan{\frac{x}{2}}$$ is not continuous at $x=\pi$
So i want to know how should i do to figure it out
Thanks in advance

Comment: Try to apart the integral domain to $[0,\pi)$ and $(\pi,2\pi]$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{1}{1-2a\cos x+a^2}dx=\int_0^{\pi}\frac{1}{1-2a\cos x+a^2}dx+\int_{\pi}^{2\pi}\frac{1}{1-2a\cos x+a^2}dx$$
And use the fact:
$$\lim_{x\to \pi^-}\tan \frac{x}{2}=\infty$$
$$\lim_{x\to \pi^+}\tan \frac{x}{2}=-\infty$$